# Prove formally that n^n is Ω(n!)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Using the formal definition:
f(n)= Ω(g(n)) iff there exists a constant 'C' such that f(n)>= cg(n) where C>0 and n approaches infinity.
When showing this informally, I was able to see, through graphing, that the statement is true.
However, I am unsure how to show this formally.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question. This is probably better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com. But a hint: use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Just write down the expansion of either expression as a product of n members.

Comment: Well, n! is equal to (n)\*(n-1)\*(n-2)\*(n-3)\*...2\*1 (n terms), and n^n is equal to n\*n\*n\*n\*...\*n (also n terms). I think it's pretty clear that the former is smaller than the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a formal proof, you can prove by induction that n^n > n! for any n>1.

The base case is that 2^2 > 2! (since 4 > 2). The induction step is that n! = n(n-1)! < n(n-1)^(n-1) < n*n^(n-1) = n^n.